# What is the difference between an immediate child and a direct child of an element

Tags: html, css

Is the `div` with class `altfoo` an immediate child of the `div` with class `foo`? Why or why not? I am confused, does immediate child mean the same thing as a direct child?

```
<div class="foo">
  <!-- 1 -->
  <p></p>
   <!-- 2 -->
  <p></p>
  <div class="altfoo">
    <!-- 3 -->
    <p></p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "immediate child" means the same thing as "direct child", and your element `.altfoo` is both an immediate and direct child of `.foo`. This can be confirmed with the **[child combinator `>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)**:

```css
.foo > .altfoo {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <!-- 1 -->
  <p></p>
   <!-- 2 -->
  <p></p>
  <div class="altfoo">
    <!-- 3 -->
    Altfoo
    <p></p>
 </div>
</div>
```

The `<p></p>` in your example is simply a **sibling** of `.altfoo`, and it is **also** a direct child of `.foo`.

A **direct** child is a child element that comes **immediately below** the parent in terms of hierarchy. That is to say, **not** a grandchild or great-grandchild.

For example, notice that when an element separates the two elements in the hierarchy, the `.foo > .altfoo` CSS selector no longer targets the element:

```css
.foo > .altfoo {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="altfoo">
      Altfoo
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could reach to child elements. One, by using the DOM property "children" which gives only the immediate child nodes of type element. While the "childNodes" function gives nodes of all type at all level including comments and text nodes. Below sample code can be run to better understand the statement.

```
<htmL>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="foo">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <div class="altfoo">
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
var c = document.getElementsByClassName("foo")[0].children; 
//var c = document.getElementsByClassName("foo")[0].childNodes();


var i;
  for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    alert( c[i].outerHTML);
  }

})();
</script>

</html>
```